# Multiple SchedulerFactory in Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a set of Quartz job for each of them I would like to attach individual HolidayCalendar (separate calendar for each job), I am thinking of a Different Scheduler factory/Scheduler object instead of single Scheduler object where I can attach Single calendar to single job. Is this correct approach? Does Quartz supports multiple factory objects in same JVM's? What's the other better approach I can try if there are any?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single Scheduler can have multiple Calendars

```
HolidayCalendar cal = new HolidayCalendar();
cal.addExcludedDate( someDate );

sched.addCalendar("myHolidays", cal, false);
```

And then associate Calendar to the trigger by Calendar Name

```
trigger.setCalendarName("myHolidays");
```

Can you try this? I think this is better approach that having multiple scheduler instances,

Comment: Thank you, I tried as you suggested above and it's working fine. I tried something like below -  for(String jobName : jobsList){  HolidayCalendar cal = new HolidayCalendar();
cal.addExcludedDate( someDateForjobName  );

sched.addCalendar("myHolidays"+jobName , cal, false);trigger.setCalendarName("myHolidays"+jobName ); }